# How to set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS in beam pipeline to resolve Access Denied Error?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to insert data in *bigquery* from a file using dataflow pipeline. Below code gives me *access denied error*.

Also I have set application credentials by environment variable. I started getting error which says

> The Application Default Credentials are not available.

I need help to resolve this. Thanks in advance. Please find below code:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import argparse
import logging
import re
import apache_beam as beam
import os
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions

class DataIngestion:

    def parse_method(self, string_input):        
        values = re.split(",",
                          re.sub('\r\n', '', re.sub(u'"', '', string_input)))
        row = dict(
            zip(('state', 'gender', 'year', 'name', 'number', 'created_date'),
                values))
        return row

def run(argv=None):
    """The main function which creates the pipeline and runs it."""
    os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "LocalPath\FileName.json"
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        '--input',
        dest='input',
        required=False,
        help='Input file to read. This can be a local file or '
        'a file in a Google Storage Bucket.',
        default='gs://python-dataflow-example/data_files/head_usa_names.csv')
    parser.add_argument('--output',
                        dest='output',
                        required=False,
                        help='Output BQ table to write results to.',
                        default='lake.usa_names')

    # Parse arguments from the command line.
    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)
    pipeline_args.extend([
        '--runner=DirectRunner',
        '--project=projectID',
        '--staging_location=staging_location',
        '--temp_location=temp_location',
    ])

    data_ingestion = DataIngestion()    
    p = beam.Pipeline(options=PipelineOptions(pipeline_args))
    (p     
     | 'Read from a File' >> beam.io.ReadFromText(known_args.input, skip_header_lines=1)     
     | 'String To BigQuery Row' >>
     beam.Map(lambda s: data_ingestion.parse_method(s))
     | 'Write to BigQuery' >> beam.io.Write(
         beam.io.BigQuerySink(           
             known_args.output,            
             schema='state:STRING,gender:STRING,year:STRING,name:STRING,'
             'number:STRING,created_date:STRING',            
             create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,            
             write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE)))
    p.run().wait_until_finish()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
    run()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the code to set the credentials inside your beam job and instead try the below command before running the job

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

The above command will set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS that will be visible to your job.